# Android project built with Gradle fails on Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build an Android project using Jenkins and Gradle. The build fails at compileUnitTestJava task, not finding any of the classes imported in the test. In Android Studio there is no problem in running the test but on Jenkins the build fails.

[image]

The test included in the project is the following:

```
package mobile_teacher.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.test.ActivityUnitTestCase;

import mobile_teacher.R;
import mobile_teacher.src.DashboardActivity;

/**
 * Created by blavi on 6/2/14.
 */
public class DashboardTest extends ActivityUnitTestCase<DashboardActivity> {

    public DashboardActivity activity;

    public DashboardTest() {
        super(DashboardActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(),
                DashboardActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent, null, null);
        activity = getActivity();
    }

    public void testLayout(){
        assertNotNull(activity.findViewById(R.id.lessonsList));
    }
}
```

And build.gradle is:

```
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
    // extend the runtime
    configurations {
        unitTestCompile.extendsFrom runtime
        unitTestRuntime.extendsFrom unitTestCompile
    }

    dependencies {
        compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'

        unitTestCompile files("$project.buildDir/classes/release")
        unitTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
        unitTestCompile 'com.google.android:android:4.0.1.2'
        unitTestCompile 'com.google.android:android-test:4.1.1.4'
    }

    // add a new unitTest sourceSet
    sourceSets {
        unitTest {
            java.srcDir file('src/tests/java')
        }
    }

    // add the unitTest task
    task unitTest(type:Test, dependsOn: assemble) {
        description = "run unit tests"
        testClassesDir = project.sourceSets.unitTest.output.classesDir
        classpath = project.sourceSets.unitTest.runtimeClasspath
    }

    check.dependsOn unitTest
```

Comment: Where is your jenkins ? is it the same architecture as your development post ? 

If not, I suggest to launch first graddle command on console first. I had an issue with a project that was not build with graddle plugin for jenkins and successfully build with command line.

If it works (or not) we may go further on investigation.

Moreover, have you tried to launch : graddle --stacktrace and graddle --debug ?

Comment: I fixed it. SourceSets were not specified in the android configuration. I've edited build.gradle. Now, when I build the project on Jenkins I receive instead unit.framework.TestSuite$1.warning FAILED
    junit.framework.AssertionFailedError at TestSuite.java:97 caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: There were failing tests. I receive this exception even with empty test or no test method at all.